# Is Possible When Using "form action = .html" in server

Tags: html

I want to asking about form action. Is that possible when I use

```
form method="POST" action = "name.html"
```

Because I still develop in static page. Thank you

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that it isn't possible? Have you tried it? Did you get an error?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this will make a POST request to `name.html`. It is up to `name.html` and the webserver on how to process that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pretty much any URL you like in the action attribute.

(URL schemes other than HTTP and HTTPS may cause issues)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use this form method="POST" action = "name.html"